# Matlab - finding the values in a vector making a neighborhood chain

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector that has values, say `a=[10 20 42 90]` and what I am trying to do is to find the neighbors in the range of 30 and replace these values with their means. For example, for the `a` vector, the value of 20 is a neighbor of 10. Additionally, 42 is also a neighbor of 10 through 20, because it is a neighbor's neighbor but 90 is not a neighboring value and it is not reachable from 10 with a neighborhood size of 30.

So I want to replace all 10, 20 and 42 with their means and obtain the vector `a=[24 90]`.

If `a=[10 20 42 66 155]`, then the resulting vector would be `a=[34.5 155]`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Just to be sure, for a window size of 30, the result for `a = [0 20 40 60 80]` would be `a = 40`?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger That's exactly the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[10 20 42 66 155]; % sample data
r = 30; % sample range

a = accumarray(cumsum([r+1 abs(diff(a))]>r).',a,[],@mean).';
```

Ungolfed and commented version:

```
a=[10 20 42 66 155]; % sample data
r = 30; % range

% difference between subsequent groupmembers. First difference is set to be higher than r
d = [r+1 abs(diff(a))];
% each group one label
L = cumsum(d>r);
% calculate mean of each group
a = accumarray(L.',a,[],@mean).';
```